# Passing data into key value pairs

Tags: android, http-post

How can I pass the data in key value pairs by using "=" in place of ":" into an `HttpPost` in Android?

Like this:

```
"firstName" = "abc"
"lastName" = "xyz"
```

Comment: Generally we pass either JSON, XML for http post request, what exact problem you're facing? share your logic and problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by using "=" in place of ":" but my guess is you are trying to post with parameters. You can try something likes this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", "abc"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", "xyz"));
try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}
```